# multithreaded client and server in distributed system (Java)

Tags: java

Am new to Socket programming am trying to establish a communication between a Server and a client but i don't know how to do that am a bit confused on how to go about it. I have written the program below but it is given error and i can't get my head round why.

```
package server;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class Server {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(7000);
                socket.setSoTimeout(0);

                while(true)
                {
                    byte []buffer = new byte[1024];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    String message = new String (buffer);
                    System.out.println(message);
                    String Reply ="Am here";
                    DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(Reply.getBytes(), Reply.getBytes().length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
                    socket.send(data);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception error){
            error.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }

}
```

Client

```
package client;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class Client {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try{

            String message = "Hello Server";
            String host = "localhost";
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, addr, 7000);
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4000);
            socket.send(packet);

            DatagramSocket sockets = new DatagramSocket(7000);
            sockets.setSoTimeout(0);

            while(true)
            {
                byte []buffer = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packets = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                sockets.receive(packets);
                String messages = new String (buffer);
                System.out.println(messages);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception error){
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

How can i get them communicated. I have heard about Multi-threading but can't get my head round how it works.

I get the following error.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:93)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:392)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:242)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:299)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:271)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:32)
```

Comment: What exact error comes up?

Comment: look at your port numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanting to send/receive from a client to a server using a socket then use [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) on the serverside.

Then use [accept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) - This listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it.

The Socket object returned by `Accept` has Input and Output Stream which can be be read and written to.

The client will just use a Socket Object

See http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/ for an example

If for some reason you insist on using DatagramSocket, then see this example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the port you are trying to bind your socket to is already in use. Port `7000` is used both by the client and server:

```
DatagramSocket sockets = new DatagramSocket(7000);
```